# Get all objects if nested array contain values - ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I want to return a list of the object if a nested list contains values from another array.
For example:

```
{
  "ListOfMainObject": [
      {
          "Name": "Object1",
          "NestedArray": [
             "Value1",
             "Value2"
          ]
      },
      {
          "Name": "Object2",
          "NestedArray": [
             "Value1",
             "Value3"
          ]
      },
      {
          "Name": "Object3",
          "NestedArray": [
             "Value2",
             "Value3"
          ]
      }
]}
```

and if I have an array, for example ["Value1"], it should return a list of Object1 and Object2. Also, If I have array ["Value1", "Value2"], it should return just Object1, because, only Object1 contain these values.

Currently, I have this filter function for setting up this query, but this exclude everything if I send two values in array:

```
private List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Unit>, QueryContainer>> GetFacetFilters(IList<string> facets)
    {
        var filters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Unit>, QueryContainer>>();

        if (facets == null)
        {
            return filters;
        }

        foreach (var facet in facets)
        {
            QueryContainer Filter(QueryContainerDescriptor<Unit> f) => f
                .Bool(bo => bo
                    .Must(m => m.MatchPhrase(md => md.Field(new Field("facets.visible")).Query("true")))
                    .Should(s => s.MatchPhrase(md => md.Field(new Field("facets.alias")).Query(facet))));

            filters.Add(Filter);
        }

        return filters;
    }
```

'Unit' is main object and 'Facets' is nested array.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. .net elastic search

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data appears to be a JSON collection but you've provided the c# and .net tags so I assume that at some point you have the capacity to operate over a set of c# objects.

Using LINQ, you may return the subset of MainObjects for which the NestedArray property contains all values of a separate Array as below:

```
List<MainObject> mainObjectList = {...} // object collection
var requiredValues = {...} // e.g. ["Value1", "Value2"];

mainObjectList.Where(x => !requiredValues.Except(x.NestedArray).Any());
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a C# object, but I wanted to be descriptive. However, I need to do that without classic linq and with using elasticsearch filters.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well I've got no experience there so hopefully someone else will have an answer for ya!